# Synergy client auto config selects wrong sever IP

Tags: macos, mac, synergy

I have [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org) (1.7.5) running as a server on a Windows 7 machine and as a client on an OS X El Capitan (10.11.3) machine. Whenever I boot up the Mac, the Synergy auto config looks for the server at `192.168.0.100`, which is wrong. I have to uncheck the auto config option and manually type in the Server IP using the keyboard and mouse attached to the Mac before I am able to use the server’s keyboard and mouse.

Where is it getting this `192.168.0.100` from and how can I change it? Is there a configuration file somewhere? I looked through the Mac’s network settings and didn’t see `192.168.0.*` at all.

Comment: Yes, the 64-bit version seems to have some serious issues.

Comment: Linux and Windows both have 32 and 64-bit versions available for download, but they don't seem to offer that choice for OS X.